# Bad gateway from Kibana behind nodejs reverse proxys

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, kibana, reverse-proxy, opensearch

I have a kibana instance behind a nodejs 16.x aws lambda reverse proxy. It works fine for almost everything, except for the "Discover" section when I add 2 or more filters for 2+ months timerange, it gives back bad gateway error.

Detail of the error:

```
Wrapper@https://mydomain/_dashboards/909221/bundles/core/core.entry.js:6:4249
_createSuperInternal@https://mydomain/_dashboards/909221/bundles/core/core.entry.js:6:3388
...
...
```

Implementation:

```
function proxy(event, context, lambdaCallback) {
    delete(event.headers["accept-encoding"])

    var path = event.path;
    if (event.multiValueQueryStringParameters) {
        path += '?' + deserializeQueryString(event.multiValueQueryStringParameters)
    }

    // Calculate the options for the HTTPS request
    var opts = {
      host: my_es_endpoint,
      path: path,
      method: event.httpMethod,
      service: 'es',
      region: my_region,
      headers: event.headers
    }

    if ((event.httpMethod == 'POST') || (event.httpMethod == 'PUT')) {
        if (event.body) {
            var buff = new Buffer(event.body, "base64")
            var payload = buff.toString('utf-8')
            opts.body = payload
        }
    }

    // Use aws4 to sign the request so we can talk with ElasticSearch directly
    aws4.sign(opts);

    const req = https.request(opts, function (res) {
        var bodyParts = [];
        // We need to read all the incoming data
        res.on('data', (chunk) => {
            bodyParts.push(chunk)
        });
        res.on("end", () => {
            // We re-create the read content
            var body = Buffer.concat(bodyParts).toString()

            // We send back uncompressed data
            delete(res.headers['content-encoding'])
            res.headers['X-Frame-Options'] = 'DENY'
            // res.headers['content-security-policy'] = "default-src 'self'; frame-ancestors 'none'"
            res.headers['X-XSS-Protection'] = '1; mode=block'
            res.headers['X-Content-Type-Options'] = 'nosniff'

            var response = {
                statusCode: res.statusCode,
                body: body,
                headers: res.headers
            }

            lambdaCallback(null, response);
        })
    });

    req.on('error', (e) => {
        console.log(`Error caught when calling ElasticSearch: ${e}`)
    })

    // For POST/PUT request, we send the content of the paylod as well
    if ((event.httpMethod == 'POST') || (event.httpMethod == 'PUT')) {
        if (event.body) {
            var buff = new Buffer(event.body, "base64")
            var payload = buff.toString('utf-8')
            req.write(payload)
        }
    }

    req.end();
    return req;
}
```

I tried:

- Incraesing timeout on request
- Increase lambda memory from 128 to 512
- Increase lambda timeout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if the error is related to the proxy implementation, however I found something that helped and now I am not experiencing the problem anymore.

I reduced the value of `discover:sampleSize` in Kibana Advanced Settings as suggested [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/discover-gateway-timeout-error/203597)